# Components are clopen in a space with a finite number of connected components

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I'm having trouble understanding why this fact is true. A lot of sites just assume it with out reason and it doesn't seem so direct to me.

Anyways, here is the theorem:

> For any topological space $(X,T)$ with finite number of components, each component is clopen.

I only know the most basic definitions of components, basically that it is a maximal connected subset around a point.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Each component is closed. Hence, the complement of each component is open. But each component is itself a finite intersection of complements of components, hence is also open.

Comment: You should write that as an answer, it's exactly what OP is looking for, and that way it can be upvoted more substantially, and be accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 12):

A connected component $C$ of a space $X$ is always closed. This follows from the following fact:

> **Lemma:** If $A$ is a connected subset of a topological space $X$, and $A\subseteq B\subseteq \overline A$, then $B$ is connected as well.

Now if $X$ has only finitely many components, then each component is complement of finitely many closed sets.

Answer (score 2):

A minor variant: since the connected components of $X$ form a partition of $X$ and there is by assumption a finite number of them we can write
$X=C_1\cup \cdots\cup C_n$. Since e.g. $C_1$ is closed, $X\setminus C_1= C_2\cup\cdots\cup C_n$ is open. On the other hand since each $C_i$ is closed the finite union (and this is what goes wrong for an infinite number of connected components) of closed sets $C_2\cup\cdots\cup C_n$ is closed. Hence $C_1$ is open as well. So we proved that $C_1$ is both closed and open, but this clearly works for any of the connected components $C_i$.

Answer (score 2):

We know that component in a topological space $X$ are always closed sets. Also, components form a partition of $X$. So if $X$ has only a finite number of components. Then complement of any component (say) $C_{i}$ in $X$ is still a union of a finite number of remaining components (i.e., the union of a finite number of closed sets) is closed set implies that $C_{i}$ is an open set. Since $C_{i}$ is any component and so each component is clopen set in X.

Answer (score 0):

As @wckrnholm commented is enough.
But I would like to add some more details so that the op can understand better.

The component of a point  $x$ in a topological space is the union of all connected subspace of $X$ which contain the point $x$.

Now the facts

- Union of connected subspaces of a topological space is conncetd if they have a point in common.
- If a subspace $S$ of $X$ is connected then every subspace $E$ of $X$ which satisfies  $S\subset E\subset \overline{S}$ also is connected.

imply that components are connected closed subsets of $X$.

Now as **@wckrnholm** commented

> Each component is closed. Hence, the complement of each component is open. But each component is itself a finite intersection of complements of components, hence is also open.